# How do I use the regex crate to match an entire INI section?

Tags: regex, rust

I am trying to match the entire section part of an INI file, but the values under each section are non standard INI and right now it is not matching up until the next section.

Here is what I have so far: `^\[GROUP2]([^[]+)`

Matching against:

```
[GROUP1]
;This is something I don't want
COMMAND(value:test)
COMMAND(value:[type="submit"])
COMMAND(value:test)
COMMAND(value:test)


[GROUP2]
;This is something I don't want
COMMAND(value:test)
COMMAND(value:[type="submit"])
COMMAND(value:test)
COMMAND(value:test)
```

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/vtvP71/2)

Comment: Regular expressions don't seem to be the right tool to parse that kind of file. You'd probably get better results using a parser library such as [nom](https://crates.io/crates/nom).

Comment: @James Do not use that with `(?s)` single line flag. Seems to [work fine in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pdhn3a/6). I continued to answer the comment here, as that's not related to Totos answer in any way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit also goes to @Toto. The Rust tag was initially not mentioned and added later on. As it cleared out, [the Rust `regex` crate does not support any look around](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.1/regex/).

> Its syntax is similar to Perl-style regular expressions, but lacks a few features like look around...

After a lot of discussion, it seems this regex worked for @James. I'm unsure how much escaping is needed for the brackets in Rust. To be on the safe side, I've escaped every literal bracket.

```
^\[GROUP2\].*(?:\r?\n\s*[^\]\[\s].*)+
```

[See the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pdhn3a/7)

- `^\[GROUP2\]` [starts](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) with the literal substring
- `.*` matches greedily [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) of [any characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) besides newline
- `(?:\r?\n\s*[^\]\[\s].*)+` matches one or more lines, [not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) starting with a bracket

Comment: Better than mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go:

```
^\[GROUP\d+]([\s\S]+?)(?=\n+(?:^\[|$))
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/vtvP71/6)

Comment: Thanks. There is a chance the groups aren't separated by a double linebreak. Is it possible to match on [ as the first character of the new line?

Comment: @James: see my edit. I made a mistake, `\z` is not supported by javascript regex.

Comment: Sorry, is there an alternative way as look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind, is not supported in rust regex

Comment: @James I think you could try like [`^\[GROUP2].*(?:\r?\n *[^\][\s].*)+`](https://regex101.com/r/pdhn3a/2) Please always specify regex flavor/environment you're using as answers can differ a lot.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks for your help. I am getting an error "unclosed character class" at this part *[^

Comment: @James Try more escaping: `^\[GROUP2\].*(?:\r?\n *[^\]\[\s].*)+`

Comment: @bobblebubble Almost.. but that selects both groups. Eg: ^\[GROUP1\].*(?:\r?\n *[^\]\[\s].*)+

Comment: @Toto Sorry for the many comments, wanted to answer James for alternative and it seemed, you were not there at the moment :)